I got livewire/update 404 (Not Found) when I switch database in the Livewire controller
The laravel app that I'm working on needs to have a dedicated database for each user (better for debugging and managing).
So basically, the user login on the database specified (DB_DATABASE)  in the .env file, and and then all other controller have a middleware that change the laravel database to use the user database (that has been created programmatically when the user registered the first time).
if (Auth::check()) 
{
         
    $user = Auth::user();

    $userDatabase = $user->database;

    Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $userDatabase);

    DB::purge('mysql');
    DB::reconnect('mysql');

    try 
    {
        $pdo = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();  // Tester la connexion PDO
    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) 
    {
        Log::error('Failed to reconnect to the database: ' . $e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }

    Log::info('Database connection successfully re-established: ' . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());

}

And it works perfectly, BUT not with livewire.
Here is my livewire controller :
class MyLiveWireController extends Component
{
    public $idCampaign;
    public $campaign;

    public function switchDatabase()
    {

        Log::info(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__);
        
        if (Auth::check()) 
        {
        
            $user = Auth::user();

            $userDatabase = "xbot_" . $user->bot_database;

            Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $userDatabase);

            DB::purge('mysql');
            DB::reconnect('mysql');

            try 
            {
                $pdo = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();  // Tester la connexion PDO
            } 
            catch (\Exception $e) 
            {
                Log::error('Failed to reconnect to the database: ' . $e->getMessage());
                throw $e;
            }

       }

       Log::info("Database : " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());

    }

    public function mount($idCampaign)
    {

        Log::info(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__ . " idCampaign = " . $idCampaign);

        $this->idCampaign = $idCampaign;

    }

    public function render()
    {
    
        Log::info(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__);

        $this->switchDatabase();

        $this->campaign = Campaign::find($this->idCampaign);

        return view('livewire.my-table', []);
    
    }

}

The livewire view :
<div wire:poll> Hello</div>

Every time the the render is called, I got :
livewire.js?id=38dc8241:4284 POST http://localhost:8000/livewire/update 404 (Not Found)
Please note that :

when I login with the admin user, which means the database is the same, the call of switchDatabase() does not cause any error.

if I remove the line $this->campaign = Campaign::find($this->idCampaign);     it works.


Of course if I use array :
$campaignData = [
    'id' => $campaign->id,
    'name' => $campaign->name
];

return view('livewire.tweet-table', [
    'campaign' => $campaignData,
]);

It works, but I really really would prefer to use eloquent collection or it will be nightmare...
Any ideas?
Thanks
